# Gnu FLex: How does yyunput works

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I have got a problem understanding flex yyunput behavior.

I want to put back some charackters

For exemple:
My scanner found CALL{space}{cc}

```
cc          N?Z|N?C|P[OE]?|M

%%
CALL{blank}{cc}         {BEGIN CON; return yy::ez80asm_parser::make_CALL(loc);}
CALL{mmode}{blank}{cc}  {BEGIN CON; return  yy::ez80asm_parser::make_CALL(loc);}
CALL                    {BEGIN ARG; return  yy::ez80asm_parser::make_CALL(loc);}
```

and I want to give back the {cc} so it will be scanned next time.

What are the both arguments of yyunput has to be? I couldn't found any helpfully information about that funktion.

Any hints are wellcome
Jürgen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "give back the {cc}" because the regular expression doesn't have pieces. (Flex does not do captures, either, so it wouldn't help to put parentheses around it.)

If you just want to rescan part of a token, it is much better to use `yyless` than `unput`, since `yyless` mostly just changes a pointer. With a single call to `yyless` you can return as many characters as you like, so you only need to know how many characters to return. (More precisely, you tell it how many characters you want to keep in `yytext`; the remainder are returned and `yytext` is truncated accordingly.)

For reference, `unput` is a macro whose single argument is a single character which will be pushed onto the beginning of the unconsumed input, overwriting `yytext` as it goes. (In the C++ API, it calls the internal member function `::yyunput`, supplying it an additional necessary argument. Don't call this function directly.)

If you need to push several characters onto the input, you need to `unput` them one at a time, *starting with the last one*. Since `unput` destroys the value of `yytext`, you need to make sure that you've already copied it if you need it before calling `unput`.

In your case, I think neither of these is appropriate. What you probably want to do is to not include the `{cc}` pattern in match in the first place, which you can do with flex's trailing context operator <kbd>/</kbd>. (That assumes that you don't need to include the characters matched by `{cc}` in the semantic value you will be returning; in the example provided, `yytext` does not appear to be part of the semantic value, so the assumption should be safe.) To do so, you might write something like:

```
CALL{mmode}?{blank}/{cc}  {BEGIN CON; return yy::ez80asm_parser::make_CALL(loc);}
CALL                      {BEGIN ARG; return yy::ez80asm_parser::make_CALL(loc);}
```

(Note: I combined your first two patterns into a single one since they seem to have the same action, but if you actually need the characters matched by `{mmode}` you might not want to do that.)

If that doesn't work, for whatever reason, use `yyless`. You'll need to know how many characters you want to return to the input, so I imagine you would end up with something like:

```
CALL{mmode}?{blank}{cc}  { BEGIN CON;
                           int to_keep = yyleng - 1;
                           switch (yytext[to_keep]) {
                             case 'C': case 'Z':
                               if (yytext[to_keep - 1] == 'N') --to_keep;
                               break;
                             case 'E': case 'O': --to_keep; break
                             case 'P': case 'N': break;
                             default: assert(false); /* internal error */
                           }
                           yyless(to_keep);
                           return yy::ez80asm_parser::make_CALL(loc);
                         }
```

For details on the trailing context operator, see the [Flex manual section on patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns) (search for the word "trailing"; there is an important note towards the end as well) as well as the first paragraph of the [following chapter on matching](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Matching.html#Matching). `yyless` and `unput` are both documented in the [chapter on actions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html#Actions), which includes examples of their usage.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for that helpful answer.

But the problem occures an the next token following the CALL and any others that will be optional followed by {cc}.
There is another tag called {reg} [ABCDEHL] which includes some parts matching by {cc} too. Depending on the order of this tags I get {reg} or {cc} next iteration :((

Comment: I have forgotten :) I'm using c++ scanner and for that yyunput has to be used. But yyunput takes two argument. An int and a char pointer.  I can't find any description about it's maining

Comment: @J.W.Sievers: In C++ scanners, you should still use `unput`, which is a macro; it will fill in the correct second argument to the `yyunput` method. (That's not well documented, I agree.) But don't use `unput`. You are not inserting new data; you just want to rescan. Either use `yyless` or the trailing context solution I recommend. I guess it would be helpful for you to show more of your patterns.

Comment: @J.W.Sievers: Updated the answer with an example of using `yyless` (which is also a macro) and a clarification on the use of `unput` in C++ scanners. (There may be a cleaner solution to all of this, but without seeing your actual requirements I can't guess what it would be, and anyway that would be a different question.)

Comment: @splash:You are right that should work for me. Unfortschittly there are a lot of Token that may be followed by {cc}. So I have to insert several times the handmade detection you suggested.
That seems to me to make my code unelegand.
Hence, it works and I can call a funktion to look what kind of {cc}.

Comment: @J.W.Sievers: Yes, it is inelegant, which is why I think you should think about how to use trailing context. Maybe you need an additional start condition to deal with the ambiguity with `{reg}`, or maybe you just need to be careful about the order of your rules.

Comment: @splash: yes, good idea, I'm redesign my scanner using states. I have a pattern that matches all operation and switching to state 'CON' or 'ARG' depending on which may follow.'code' cc     N[ZC]?|P[OE]?|M
opc   (A(D[CD]|ND)|BIT|C(ALL|CF|P(DR?|IR?|L)?)|D(AA|EC|I|JNZ)|E(X{1,2}|I)|HALT|I(M|N([0C]|[DI][2M]?R?)?)|J[PR]|L(D(DR?|IR?)?|EA)|MULT|N(EG|OP)|O(R(I2R)?|T[DI][2M]?R?|UT0?)|P(EA|OP|USH)|R(E(S|T[IN]?))|[LR](C?A?|D?)|S(TMIX|T)|S(BC|CF|ET|L[AP]|R[AL]|MIX|UB)|TS[RT]|XOR)